# How to convert CSV file to a specific JSON format with nested objects?

Tags: python, json, csv

I want to populate my json message with data from a CSV file. I want each row to be a "new" json object. I am using Python and will connect the the code to an API once done. Some of the data needs tp be categorized under "personalinfo" and "carinfo" and I need the correct data to be populated under the right category as under the "Expected json message output" below.

This is what I have so far:

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('test.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('file.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("firstname","r", "lastname","r", "age","r", "gender","r",
              "model","r", "price","r", "loan","r")
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
out = json.dumps( [ row for >row in reader ] )
jsonfile.write(out)
```

I do not know how to add the two "personalinfo" and "carinfo" categories.

Example csv table:

```
 FirstName  LastName    Age gender  Car model Price loan
    Anna    Andersson   28  F       Audi    A8 40    FALSE
```

Expected json message output:

```
{
    "personalinfo": {
        "firstname": "Anna",
        "lastname": "Andersson",
        "age": "28",
        "gender": "F",

        "carinfo": [{
            "car": "Audi",
            "model": "A8"
        }],

        "price": 40,
        "loan": "FALSE"
    }
}
```

Next record should be a new json object.

Comment: Have you tried anything or are you asking us to do it for you?

Comment: Well... that output isn't valid JSON... How far have you got with that, and is your source data a pandas DataFrame or is that just how you've presented the data?

Comment: @johnashu added the code

Comment: I don't think Anna and Bea will take it lightly, that you've set a price on them and made them available for loan. Maybe you should move those properties to their cars? Also "car   " is not a valid json identifier, you need to get rid of the blanks.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have tried, please see the added code

Comment: @PalleDue changed the json format, the meaning is more that there are 3 records combined in the json, one about personal info of the car owner, the car model, and than the bank details of the car payment. The information is coming from 3 tables in a database and has been combined

Comment: @hlch123: OK, I see. But your carinfo is an array, so I thought they might have more cars. Anyway, the loan details are in the personal info and so is car info, only as an internal object.

Answer (score 5):

You need to convert each row of data in the csv file into a JSON object laid-out the way you described. This can be accomplished by calling a single function which takes the `row` dictionaries from the csv file using a `csv.DictReader` and does just that:

```
import csv
import json

def make_record(row):
    return {
               "personalinfo": {
                   "firstname": row["FirstName"],
                   "lastname": row["LastName"],
                   "age": row["Age"],
                   "gender": row["gender"],
                   "carinfo": [
                       {
                           "car": row["Car"],
                           "model": row["model"]
                       }
                   ],
                   "price": int(row["Price"]),
                   "loan": row["loan"]
               }
           }


with open('csv_test.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile, \
     open('json_file.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    out = json.dumps([make_record(row) for row in reader], indent=4)
    jsonfile.write(out)

# Show results.
with open('json_file.json', 'r') as jsonfile:
    print('results:')
    print(json.dumps(json.load(jsonfile), indent=4))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import json

csv_file = 'YourCsvFile.csv'
json_output = []

with open(csv_file, 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        template = {
            "Columen1": row["Columen1"],
            "Columen2": row["Columen2"],
            "Columen3": row["Columen3"],
            "Columen4": row["Columen4"],
            "Columen5": row["Columen5"],
            "Columen6": row["Columen6"],
            "Columen7": [],
            "Columen8": []
        }

        if row["Columen7"]:
            rule = {
                "Id": "Material",
                "Value": row["Columen7"],
                "Operator": "Contain"
            }
            template["Columen7"].append(rule)

        if row["Columen8"]:
            automation = {
                "Id": "Motion Type",
                "Value": row["Columen8"]
            }
            template["Columen8"].append(automation)

        json_output.append(template)

json_data = json.dumps(json_output, indent=4)

# Print or write the JSON data to a file
print(json_data)


# Asum this is your Json Template/ CSV should contain 8 columns 
json = {
    "Columen1": "Furniture Accessories",
    "Columen2": "Floor Protectors",
    "Columen3": "10",
    "Columen4": "100",
    "Columen5": "1010",
    "Columen6": "10104",
    "Columen6": [
        {
            "Id": "Material",
            "Value": "leather|leather Match",
            "Operator": "Contain"
        }
    ],
    "Columen6": [
        {
            "Id": "Motion Type",
            "Value": "Swivles"
        }
    ]
}

# By Redhwan Ghailan
```