# Assigning multiple values to a dictionary to write as json data?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a program to scrape urls of my favourite podcasts. I want to then create a local website from latter data.

I'm trying to create a dictionary I can then use to write as a json file and then access that data using javascript.

I would like the dictionary to look like:

```
{"url": "www.test.com", "text" : "Podcast 1... foo bar"}
```

I'm having trouble assigning the values however. What I have so far:

```
def findLinks(url):
    filename = url[-16:-4] + ".json"
    response = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a'))

    for link in soup:
        if link.has_key('href'):
            links[link.attrMap['href']] = link.getText() #Dictionary

    writeToJSON(filename, links)
```

Comment: Could you do something along [these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47757432/355230)?

Answer (score 0):

Create the dictionary like this:

```
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        links = {'url': link.get('href'), 'text': link.get_text()}
```

If you do this in a loop, however, the values in `links` will be replaced as each link is processed, and you wil end up with only one dictionary saved to the file. For that reason you should probably use a list of dictionaries instead. Append each dictionary to the list as you go:

```
links = []
for link in soup:
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        links.append({'url': link['href'], 'text': link.get_text()})
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
links = [{'url': link['href'], 'text': link.get_text()} for link in soup if link.has_attr('href')]
```

Finally, write it to a file in JSON format:

```
writeToJSON(filename, links)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def findLinks(url):
    temp_list = []
    filename = url[-16:-4] + ".json"
    response = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a'))

    for link in soup:
        if link.has_key('href'):
          result_dict = {'url': link['href'], 'text': link.get_text()}
          temp_list.append(result_dict)

    json.dump(temp_list,open(filename,'w'))
```